# 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, iterable

I'm trying to create a program that computes the average and standard deviation of a given list of numbers.
The mean works fine but the standard deviation(sd) will give me the float not iterable error

```
from math import sqrt
def mean(xs):
    return sum(xs)/len(xs)

def sd(xs):
    for x in xs:
        a=sqrt(sum(x-mean(xs)\*\*2)/(len(xs)-1))
    return a

def computeMeasure(xs, unit):
    return (mean(xs), sd(xs), unit)


xs = [11,12,13,14,11,11,12,10,15]
print(f'{mean(xs):6.3f}, {sd(xs):5.3f}')
```

I've also tried to use the range function but that in turn gives me the error

```
for x in range(xs):

'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: The way you calculate standard deviation is incorrect. You should calculate the sum using the loop first, and only then use the square root.

Comment: The error doesn't match the error you complain about and the code in the error doesn't match the code in your question. Please provide a clear [mre]

Answer (score 2):

The `sum()` function in python takes an iterable as input.

```py
a=sqrt(sum(x-mean(xs)**2)/(len(xs)-1))
```

In this line, `sum(x-mean(xs)**2)` float object is passed into the `sum()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct version:

```
from math import sqrt
def mean(xs):
    return sum(xs)/len(xs)

def sd(xs):
    x=[(num-mean(xs))**2 for num in xs]
    return sqrt(sum(x)/(len(xs)-1))

def computeMeasure(xs, unit):
    return (mean(xs), sd(xs), unit)

xs = [11,12,13,14,11,11,12,10,15]
print(f'{mean(xs):6.3f}, {sd(xs):5.3f}')
```